# Comparisons between Quorum Constellation and Tessera

Tags: blockchain, quorum

This is regarding Transaction managers of Quorum Private blockchain, i.e. Tessera and Constellation.

Can someone highlight few key technical reasons that make Tessera better than Constellation.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Constellation developments are nearly stopped while Tessera still get updates:
https://github.com/jpmorganchase/tessera
https://github.com/jpmorganchase/constellation

For having tested both, Tessera is much more stable and throw fewer errors.